# Is there any way to change the creator PDF generation in spipu/html2pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tcpdf, html2pdf

I've been using [spipu/Html2Pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) version 5.2 in `laravel 5.8` to generating PDF, and trying to set my own creator name on the PDF (by default the creator is **Html2Pdf - TCPDF**)

Is that any way to change it via Html2Pdf class (without modifying the vendor)? or am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator name comes from TCPDF package (A package Html2Pdf uses) and I think it can be changed with the following:

```php
$html2pdf = new \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->pdf->setCreator('CREATOR NAME');
```